# Is there a possibility where we can pass "SYSDATE" in Date From Option while creating a date parameter in Oracle BIP?

Tags: bi-publisher

I have a requirement in preparing a report where we are having a date parameter  in which user should be allowed to select a date, starting from SYSDATE to all other future dates.

For instance, If we hardcode the value as '01-01-1990' for "Date From" option, it is working fine. But if we enter the value as any of the following ("SYSDATE","SYSDATE()", "{$SYSDATE()$}") then it is not working properly.

The user should not be able to select any date before the sysdate.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVlEK.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the concurrent program configuration, set the default value of the date parameter to ‘select sysdate from dual’

Comment: if we set the default to SYSDATE, it's just for the display purpose right??.. In that case the user can still select the previous dates from the calendar

Comment: From the screen shot I see now, doesn't look like you are using EBS, which I expected. So I'm a little less sure of the solution. But any default should be changeable by the user, and also submitted along with the request.